# Ansible erroring out eventually during provisioning process

Tags: python, provisioning, ansible

While provisioning a server with Ansible 1.9.1 from a OS X host, I get the following error at random points of the provisioning process:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => 
{'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': 
    [{'invocation': {'module_name': 'somemodule', 'module_args': ''},
    'item': {'priv': 'ALL', 'moreitems'}, 'changed': False, 'user': ''}, 
            {'msg': 'FAILED: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 
              54] Connection reset by peer', 'failed': True}]}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Why is the connection reset by peer at random points is beyond me. I have no configuration for paramiko logging what-so-ever.

If this bug on Ansible, on the linux server, on the OS X host, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being Python 2.6 version of pycrypto.

The [solution from *dennen99*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/276) fixed it for me.

I'm assuming that upgrading to Python2.7 would also fix the problem (not tested by me).